# I want to create a button that only does an action but not redirect to a specified path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to ruby on rails but I want to create a button that only switches from dark mode to light mode and vice versa. I see that is required to specify the path to be able to recognise the action but I don't need a View. Is there a way to only call the action without the path?
I solved this by redirecting the user to the current page he is actually but I don't like this approach. I there a way to only call the action and nothing else.
I think the routing is not needed here since I want just to update the dark_mode variable on the database on click of the dark_mode button.

the action

```
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
      @user.update_attribute :dark_mode, !@user.dark_mode
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
   end
```

the view of the button

```
    <% if current_user.dark_mode == false %>
      <li><%= link_to t(:activate_dark_mode), dark_mode_switch_path %></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to t(:deactivate_dark_mode), dark_mode_switch_path %></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
    <% end %>
```

te routes

```
  get 'dark_mode'=> "users#dark_mode_switch", as:'dark_mode_switch'
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Add `remote: true` to your `link_to` method:

   ```
   <%= link_to t(:activate_dark_mode), dark_mode_switch_path, remote: true %>
   ```
2. Add `head :ok` to action:

   ```
   def action
     @user = User.find(current_user.id)
     @user.update_attribute :dark_mode, !@user.dark_mode
     head :ok
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The action on completion leads to a redirection because you have asked it to by executing a redirect after updating the user record `redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)`

Instead let the link make a XHR request to your server and in response either render a JS template which may notify the user **OR** dont do anything(bad !! the user should know if something was successful).

```
 def change_mode
   @user = User.find(current_user.id)
   @user.update_attribute :dark_mode, !@user.dark_mode
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end
 end
```

In `app/views/**/change_mode.js.erb` (any view template can be rendered but the default would be something like the above.

```
alert("Mode Changed"); // You may append message in a div also. Alert is for demo.
```